# componentWillRecieveProps vs getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs

componentWillRecieveProps is deprecated and getDerivedStateFromProps is being advocated to use.

But componentWillRecieveProps gets called when the props get changed but getDerivedStateFromProps is getting called on any state change even.

My requirement is to reset state on  props change. So how would I get to know if the props really got changed.

I am not in favor of storing the props value in state as it would unnecessarily make the state bulkier and I still not have given state management(Redux or Context API) a thought

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how would I get to know if the props really got changed.

Compare previous prop with new prop.

For simplest use case, just use [`componentDidUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate), with prop comparing:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) {
    this.fetchData(this.props.userID);
  }
}
```

According to [React Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate), it is OK to perform side effect or `setState()` inside `componentDidUpdate()`.

And `setState()` can cause re-rendering, which affects component performance. When performance in this case is actually a thing, read on: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#when-to-use-derived-state